# Stability and existence of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem $$x'=-x^2\sin(t),\ x(0)=a, \ a \in \mathbb R$$

I need to find out for which $t \ge 0$ the solutions exists, depending on $a \in \mathbb R$ and reason if the solution $x(t)=0$ is stable or asymptotically stable.

My solution for the IVP is $x(t)=\frac{a}{1+a-a\cos(t)}$

So I would say it exsists for $a \cos(t) \neq 1+a \Leftrightarrow t \neq \arccos(1/a+1)$. But $\arccos(y)$ is only defined for $y \in [-1,1]$. So what's the correct answer to the first question?

And how can I show if the solution $x(t)$ is is stable or asymptotically stable?

Answer (score 1):

The denominator can also be written as $1+2a\sin^2\frac t2$. In this form it is obvious that for $a>-\frac12$ it is never zero, meaning that there is no singularity in the solution, it exists for all times. In the other cases the domain of the solution is finite.